# WordPress - WP Admin bar missing when visiting my website

Tags: wordpress

I tried all of these to check why the `WP admin bar` is missing on my site.

- Deactivate all plugins
- checked `wp_footer()` and `wp_header`
- Clear cache
- Tool bar is checked on my user profile

Have I missed anything?

PS: `WP admin bar` appears on my dashboard. It disappears on my front end website.

Comment: You might have a function, hiding it - or you're not logged in :)

Comment: This for instance, would hide it on frontend :  `add_filter(‘show_admin_bar’, ‘__return_false’); `

Comment: @Stender of course I'm logged in lol. I'll check all my functions

Answer (score 0):

Search for: `add_filter('show_admin_bar'`, remove if found. Check under your user account that **Show Toolbar when viewing site** is ticked.

Then, search for `#wpadminbar` to see if it's disabled via CSS.

If none of these help, switch a theme. If it's in the theme, narrow down the culprit. I hope this helps.